# Can angular-translate support multi-line translations?

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

I have some translations now that are paragraphs of text which quickly become tedious to manage  as single JSON strings:

```
{
  "a": {
    "b": "This is a really long translated value I have here..."
  }
}
```

I think ideally I would like to be able to represent the values differently and then transform them. For example as an array of strings that would be concatenated together:

```
{
  "a": {
    "b": [
      "This is a really long ", 
      "translated value ",
      "I have here..."
    ]
  }
}
```

Does [angular-translate](/questions/tagged/angular-translate) have the appropriate hooks to achieve this?? And if so, what is the best approach?